# window refresh clears the API response in Angular4

Tags: c#, angular, api

In my Angular4 application I have binded the API response ,From the API response I have assigned the image path in the component,When I load the specific component first time Image paths(API response) are assigned and images are displayed,If I refresh the browser window the images are gone.

While refresh the network option in chrome the API response array length is 0.Initially it shows the actual length of the API.

So how can I prevent the API response to be get cleared.

API Code...

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/data/GetImage")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetImage(string imageName)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlParameter[] sqlParameters = new SqlParameter[2];
                if (imageName != " ")
                {
                    sqlParameters[0] = new SqlParameter("@Action", "SET_IMAGE");
                    sqlParameters[1] = new SqlParameter("@IMAGE_NAME", imageName);
                }
                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds = conn.executeStoredProcedure_Dt("SP_ECOM_ImageBinding", sqlParameters);
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ds.Tables);
                }
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
        }
```

Service File

```
get_Image_Path(pName: string): Observable<Images[]> {
    this.current_product = pName.trim();
    this.serviceUrl = `http://localhost:abc/api/data/GetImage/?imageName=${this.current_product}`;
    return this.http.get<Images[]>(this.serviceUrl);
  }
```

Model

```
export interface Images {
    big_Images: string[];
    small_Images: string[];
    selected_Product_Images: string[]
  }
```

Component

```
 ngOnInit() {

    this.CartdataService.pcast.subscribe(myproduct => this.product_Name = myproduct);
    this.CartdataService.get_Image_Path(this.product_Name)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.bigImages = data['0'];
          this.smallImages = data['1'];
          this.spImages = data['2'];
          this.i_path = this.bigImages['0']['big_Images'];
        });
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
   <img *ngFor="let smallImage of smallImages; let i = index" 
     (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)"  
     [src]="smallImage['small_Images']"
     [alt]="'img' + i" 
     class="img-thumbnail" 
     [attr.ref]="bigImages[i]['big_Images']">
</div>
```

Here when the user hover on a small image it will show big size image of the hovered image.

In my case images path are get cleared when I refresh the browser window .
Thanks.

Comment: Can you attach the screenshots of api call  request data before refresh and  api call request data after refresh

Comment: You could use `local_storage` to store these data, but I don't really know how efficient a lot of data can be stored there. There are also some alternatives to keep data stored in JS/TS while the browser is open. Try [google](https://www.google.de/search?q=js+persistent+storage)

Comment: @SuvethanNantha ,Please see the attached images

Comment: @Nikson did you check the parameter passed to get_Image_Path when refreshing the page? is it passing correctly?

Comment: @SuvethanNantha,I have checked it now ,The selected product name is not passed to the API call method,

How Can I resolve this issue

Comment: @Nikson check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know behavior subject can be used to access globally until one request life cycle. If we refresh the page again new BehaviourSubject will get instantiated with the default value. That's the reason, the product_Name is passed as empty when you refresh the page.

Try this

**Component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.CartdataService.pcast.subscribe(myproduct => this.product_Name = myproduct);
    this.CartdataService.get_Image_Path(this.product_Name)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.bigImages = data['0'];
          this.smallImages = data['1'];
          this.spImages = data['2'];
          this.i_path = this.bigImages['0']['big_Images'];
        });
  }
```

**service.ts**

```
public product = new BehaviorSubject<any>(''); 
pcast = this.product.asObservable(); 

localprod;
constructor(){
    this.localprod=localStorage.getItem('product');
    if(this.localprod!='' || this.localprod!=undefined)
    {
      this.product.next(this.localprod);
    }
}

get_Product(product: string) { 
    this.current_product = product.trim(); 
    this.product.next(this.current_product);
    localStorage.setItem('product', this.current_product);
}
```

[Demo for **BehaviorSubject** with refresh page](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-behaviorsubject-with-refresh-handle)

I hope this will resolve your problem. If you still have any issues let me know.

Comment: @Nikson can you tell me what is pcast? is it another API call? check whether you are getting the response when you refresh it for product_Name

Comment: product name is get from the onclick function of another component and the value is passed to the service file from the service file I import the product name for api call of getting image path

Comment: are you Subject in your service file to to import the product name

Comment: public product = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
  pcast = this.product.asObservable();

 get_Product(product: string) {
    this.current_product = product.trim();
    this.product.next(this.current_product);
  }

by using these line I get the product name fron one componet and make it as global access

Comment: I have used the above code in my service file ,and subscribe the product name in my-cart component for passing the parameter for API call

Comment: Here what I have understand is when I refresh the window the parameter to the method get_Image_Path is not passed.For the first time the parameter is passed as well,For the second call it's not passing

Comment: it's solved my problem now ,but instead of using local storage is there any other way to handle this ...

Comment: @Nikson In order to handle these kind of problem,we need to either use LocalStorage,SessionStorage or Cookies based on our requirement. Other than that, as far as I know there is no other option. This is the standard and recommended way of handling this kind of problems.

Comment: okay thanks a lot. and can you please explain why are you  place the session storage code inside the constructor of service file.

Comment: Whenever you refresh the page,service file will get downloaded and BehaviorSubject property will be initialized again with the default value.  Therefore, when a refresh happens we need to set the value from localstorage and assign it BehaviorSubject to maintain the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,You saved my day

Comment: @nikson when you refresh the page all pages and contents will be downloaded. keep it in mind. I hope you understood my explanation

Comment: can you please help me in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49725473/how-to-bind-products-dynamically-in-snippet-carousel-in-angular4

Comment: @nikson sorry just now I saw your comment, I hope you have fixed that now